# How to change character # to be = in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have a very simple VBA code, but I can't get it work for some reason. I have a Excel sheet full of inactive formulas that have # instead of = that would make them active. I am trying to simply change the `Chr(35)` to be `Chr(61)`. But all I get is:

Run-time error '1004'

[image]

```
Sub macro4()
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(35), Chr(61))

    Next
End Sub
```

Still, if  I change the `Chr(61)` to be anything else like `Chr(62)`, it works. But not with the (`Chr61`). Why? What should I do?

Comment: Hey a-tone welcome to stackoverflow!

Could you give an example of the value of `Cell.Value` in your function `macro4()`?

Comment: #D5+F5-E5+(IF(B1#A1;C1;D1))

Comment: Change `Cell.Value` to `Cell.FormulaLocal` and it should work. But a better option would be to use `Range.Replace` - you can record a macro of using Ctrl+H functionality to see how it should look.

Comment: Thanks! Cell.FormulaLocal did it. How should I use the Range.Replace or Selection.Replace?

Comment: e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) and you may use to single cells, many cells, or entire sheet and so on.

Comment: I tried to do it like this, but it does not replace anything:

´´´
  Range("B7:L2506").Select

    Selection.Replace What:=Chr(35), Replacement:=Chr(61), LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
´´´

Why?

Answer (score -1):

Please try to replace you for loop with the code below

```vb
For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If Cell.HasFormula Then Cell.Formula = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(35), Chr(61))
Next
```

Comment: This works if I take the R1C1 off but it takes for ages to make the replacements compared to normal find&replace without VBA which made over 14000 replacements in less than a second.

I guess I need to find another solution or define the range or something.